# React-Native App giving and error while loading in my physical device

Tags: react-native

I build up a simple app with react native and its nicely work in my emulator. Then i tried to run it in smartphone using USB debug option. I can see the app in my phone under apps list, but when i try to open it for further developments its shows this error. Any idea what i am missing for react-native run-android in a physical device? I am working in a windows PC

error

"Unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle'. Make sure your bundle is packaged correctly or you're running packager server"